# Semantic markup for very fuzzy dates

Tags: html, time, semantic-markup, microformats

I'm displaying very fuzzy dates, currently in `<span>` elements, for a series of `<li>` items, e.g.

```
<li>
  <h1>The Big Lebowski 2</h1>
  <span>Spring</span>
</li>
```

I'd like to use something more semantic than a `<span>`, but from reading up on the subject [here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element) it doesn't seem that the `<time>` element is intended for such nonspecific periods of time.

Is there another option or way to use `<time>` properly to display this type of information? It seems microformats might be what I'm looking for but I'm very unfamiliar with them; any input appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "fuzzy dates"? How fuzzy?

Comment: Either seasons or periods of more than one month, e.g. May/June.

Comment: What do you expect to benefit from using “something more semantic”? Which software would interpret the semantics, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in HTML specifications or HTML5 drafts or the WHATWG “Living HTML” for expressing a period of time, still less an fuzzy period, beyond the point that a year, a month, etc. (expressed with the `time` element) can be regarded as a period (e.g., from the start of a year till the end of the year).

In [microformats](http://microformats.org/), as well as in comparable systems (microdata, RDFa) for detailed microdata associated with HTML elements, you can express metadata e.g. for [events](http://www.schema.org/Event), with properties like `startDate` and `endDate` – but they are, at least in the Schema.org approach that major search engines are said to favor, specific date (and time) notations.

Comment: "There is nothing […] for expressing a period of time": Note that you *can* specify [durations](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/infrastructure.html#durations) (as number of seconds, but not from a specific date to date, though) with `time`.